# Can we script files present on a different server using API call (like using UI)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ssh

I'm looking for a solution where I want execute Python script file present on a server using an API call, like request to start running script for a specific time interval until it didn't stop.

I'm looking for a solution using .NET Core and C#.

I was thinking that if we can connect SSH on the server when API is called then we can run the script file. I don't know to implement this. Looking for some suggestions and code help.

Comment: Could you pls explain more about your requirement? I can't  understand it well. script presenting on a server can be executed by code running in the server and the running script would only affect the server itself. Let's say I have a bat file in my server which will open the browser in my server. And I have an API project, and when I hit this API, it would run the bat file I put in the desktop of the server which means when the API is hit, my server would open one browser instance. I call the API in my client comptuer, then there would be opening a browser instance in the server.